# How can I use stdin while piping data when using promptui?

Tags: go, stdin

I am trying to write a simple cli using `promptui` and everything is working as expected; till I try to pipe data to it. After some debugging and digging around, I realized that this is so because `stdin` is being used already when piping so that stdin is being interpreted and any control characters from the pipe is breaking the prompt. (with control+d) in this case.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/manifoldco/promptui"
)

var items = []string{"some", "thing"}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Is from pipe %t\n", isFromPipe())
    // read data from pipe and do something
    // ... doesnt effect this prompt
    prompt := promptui.Select{
        Stdout:            os.Stderr,
        // Stdin:             os.Stderr, // testing to see if stdin is what is breaking
        StartInSearchMode: true,
        Label:             "pick something",
        Items:             items,
        Searcher: func(input string, index int) bool {
            d := items[index]
            name := strings.Replace(strings.ToLower(d), " ", "", -1)
            input = strings.Replace(strings.ToLower(input), " ", "", -1)
            return strings.Contains(name, input)
        },
    }

    _, result, err := prompt.Run()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Prompt failed %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("You choose %q\n", result)
}

func isFromPipe() bool {
    fi, _ := os.Stdin.Stat()
    return fi.Mode()&os.ModeCharDevice == 0
}
```

When I uncomment `StdIn`, the prompt will work, but input will not work.

So my question is:

- Can I use a different `io.ReaderCloser` to replace `os.Stdin` while still being able to read from stdin?
- How can I pipe data and still have the prompt work?